# How do I pass variable in a if loop

Tags: matlab

I have several IF loops and there are some stuff I'am repeating within all IF loops e.g:

```
    ` If(someConditions) 
           set(colour,'b', font etc…) 
        end`

    ` If(someConditions) 
           set(colour,'b', font etc…) 
        end`
```

Is there any way I can make set() method a global variable so that I can pass into a IF loop just a method? This is what I did but it does not work?

```
   ` 
      variable=colour,'b', font etc…;
        If(someConditions) 
           set('variable'); 
        end`

    ` If(someConditions) 
           set('variable'); 
        end`
```

Comment: Are you sure this is some matlab code ? It doesn't look like some. Please post the entire code.

Comment: @Crazyrat yes its a matlab code, can you give me a little example how would I pass variable within a IF loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special scope defined within an `if` condition in Matlab, *i.e.* all variables defined outside the condition are accessible within the condition.

I guess your problem is elsewhere. Does the following piece of code help you ?

```
figure
h = text(1,1, 'Test');

% Define variables
col = 'b';
varname = 'FontName';
varvalue = 'Arial';

% Condition
if true

    % First syntax, only the value is in a variable
    set(h, 'Color', col);

    % Second syntax, both the name and value of the parameter are in a variable
    set(h, varname, varvalue); 
end
```

Then, I strongly recommend that you read more about [language fondamentals](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/index.html#language-fundamentals). For instance there should not be a capital "i" at `if`, there is no need for parenthesis around the condition, and `set` is a reserved word that cannot be used as you did in your exemple code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that changes the parameters you want. Its input argument could be the graphic object you are plotting, a line for example. Of course you could make the function general to deal with many conditions, but with the info you provided it's hard to guess. This might actually be quite an overkill but it could be useful to you.

Anyhow here is a simple example that you could use to change the `FontName` and `Color` properties of text whenever some condition is met, i.e. you enter the `if` loop. The same could be done with any properties of lines you plot for example.

```
function ChangeText(CurrentText) %// The input argument is the handle to the text being displayed. That could be anything such as an axes, a figure, a scatter plot, etc.

FontName = 'Times';
Color = 'r';

set(CurrentText,'FontName',FontName,'Color',Color)

end
```

Then let's say in you script with the `if` statement you run into the condition of interest, you could simply call the function like so:

```
plot(x,y);

hText = text(x,y, 'Text here')

if SomeCondition

ChangeText(hText) %// Pass the handles of the text as argument to the function

...
end
```

This is a very simple example; hope this is what you meant. You could generalize everything with a `switch/case` statement in the function so that you could check the condition and change everything inside the function.